# R wordcloud-finding frequency per block of text

Tags: r, word-cloud

I have a CSV file of data that contain phrases like :

```
dd<-c("hello how are you?";"I am fine"; "hello how are you?"; "not too bad")
```

I want to get the frequency of each block of sentences (divided by `;`) using wordcloud. However, what I get is the frequency per word.

Is there a way to get the frequency per block of content in each cell?

In this toy example I would get:

```
Text                   Freq 
----------------------------
hello how are you?     2

I am fine              1

not too bad            1
```

Thank you very much in advance

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, try this

```
library(wordcloud)
library(tm)
txt <- c("hello how are you? I am fine", "hello how are you?; not too bad")
semicolonTonekizer <- function(x) unlist(strsplit(as.character(x), ";", fixed = TRUE))
tdm <- TermDocumentMatrix(Corpus(VectorSource(txt)), list(tokenize = semicolonTonekizer))
tab <- rowSums(as.matrix(tdm))
wordcloud(names(tab), tab)
```

Comment: You might add something like scale = c(1, .2) so that the three phrases fit on the page.